# My video won't start playing, even when i hit play button html

Tags: html, video

this is probably very simple, but I can't find the answer anywhere.
so I try to make a video with just html, but the video won't start playing, not even when i hit the start button, I tried it on IE aswell, and it said: Error: Video playback was aborterd.
Here is my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="item">
 <div class="video">
    <video width="600px" controls>
    <source src="video/banner.MP4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
  </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you open a `head` tag and you never close it. The inverse is true for your `body` tag

Comment: remove `px` from `width=600px` , and try to add an `ogg` file as well,

Comment: and as soon as I go over the video with my pause, i can't click the play button at all anymore

Comment: On which version of IE have You checked it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated answer, give it a try,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="video">
            <video width="600" controls>
                <source src="video/banner.MP4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesn't work, that's the code on w3schools, but i coppied that already.

Comment: But you have some mistakes like you never ended you head tag, and also set `width="600px"` which is not allowed,

Comment: What about video file are you doing fine setting your video source,

Comment: ahh it worked, i just changed the video. @securedevelopr